# What is a background push notification? Android, Urban Airship

Tags: android, background, push-notification, urbanairship.com

When extending the Urban Airship class **BaseIntentReceiver** there is a method which is called **onBackgroundPushReceived**, when is it triggered?

When the app is in the background and a push arrives the method **onPushReceived** is called.. so in which state needs the app to be in in order to trigger **onBackgroundPushReceived**? Or is a background push something different from a normal push?

Answer (score 1):

From their [documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/push/BaseIntentReceiver.html#onBackgroundPushReceived(android.content.Context,%20com.urbanairship.push.PushMessage)): onBackgroundPushReceived is called when a push is received that did not result in a notification being posted.

> protected abstract void onBackgroundPushReceived (Context context, PushMessage message)
>
> Called when a push is received that did not result in a notification being posted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however it is still unclear to me, sadly the documentation is lacking

Comment: It's a notification that was received that does not include any UI involvement. EG, the user will not know that a push was received.

Comment: For instance, a lightweight push which tells the app to sync?

Answer (score 0):

In the same application we can use different notification services. whenever a
push is received from a notification service other than the UrbanAirship notification service, onBackgroundPushReceived() will be called.In my application I used UrbanAirship as well as Gimbal Notification Service.So whenever push is received from Gimbal , this method is called.Inside this method I fired the local broadcast to notify the application about the arrival of new notification.